# How can I lint / audit / validate YML to avoid making stupid mistakes?

Tags: configuration

Is there a way to lint YML to ensure that the values are something that Drupal understands?

For example, I recently wrote this YML for a custom module:

**config/install/mymodule.settings.yml**

```
langcode: en
rate_limit:
  count_anon: 500
```

**config/schema/mymodule.settings.schema.yml**

```
mymodule.settings:
  type: config_object
  mapping:
    rate_limit:
      type: mapping
      mapping:
        count_anon:
          label: 'Maximum post count for anonymous users'
          type: number
```

The mistake is that I wrote `number` instead of `integer` for the `type` in the schema (doing too much JavaScript lately).  However, when I enabled the module, Drupal imported this config without complaint, but it stored `500` as a string.

It would be great if Drupal threw an error when the config to import doesn't match the schema, but since that doesn't happen, is there any way to lint or validate this?

Comment: Why doesn’t config import have strict typing? That seems to be the question asked. It’s nothing to do with YAML validity. And it seems like a feature request.

Comment: Is this what config validation is aiming to correct?

Comment: @cilefen Specifically, `type: number` is valid as YAML in terms of syntax, but it is not a valid value for Drupal because there is no `number` type.  But my real concern here is these valid-YAML-but-invalid-as-a-Drupal-value values.

Comment: Does this question have an answer? Or is it more like this is a feature or bug report?

Comment: Yes, this question has an answer.  The answer is either, "Yes, there is a way to validate/lint the config, which is XYZ," or "No, there are no tools for doing this, so make sure you define the config correctly."

Comment: Eslint can find and correct indention. I don't know what there is for number vs integer.